# Can Unison transfer the executable flag?

Tags: permissions, rsync, chmod, unison

I create a Unison setup between my work computer and my desktop at home. This way, I can continue my work at home (and vice versa), even when I forgot to commit something to GIT at work (and vice versa).

In my Unison profile, I am using the following properties:

```
auto          = true
batch         = true
silent        = false
confirmbigdel = false
times         = false
perms         = 0
prefer        = newer
copythreshold = 0
copyprog      = /usr/bin/rsync -avz -X --checksum --partial --append-verify -e ssh
copyprogrest  = /usr/bin/rsync -avz -X --checksum --partial --append-verify -e ssh
```

This does the job, except for one small thing: the executable flag is not transferred. When I apply changes on a `.sh` file at work, I have to manually do `chmod +x` again on my computer at home.

Is it possible to transfer this flag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [manual](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#prefs):

> **perms n**
>
> The integer value of this preference is a mask indicating which permission bits should be synchronized. It is set by default to 0o1777: all bits but the set-uid and set-gid bits are synchronised (synchronizing theses latter bits can be a security hazard). If you want to synchronize all bits, you can set the value of this preference to −1. If one of the replica is on a FAT [Windows] filesystem, you should consider using the t fat preference instead of this preference. If you need Unison not to set permissions at all, set the value of this preference to 0 and set the preference t dontchmod to t true.

- `perms -1` will do what you want.